# How do I give a container access to a device file in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Or to put it another way, what can I do in kubernetes so that the container is run with the equivalent of --device=/dev/tty10, as an example. Otherwise accessing a device like that gives an error.

```
[root@87eb47e75ed4 /]# echo foo >> /dev/tty10
bash: /dev/tty10: Operation not permitted
```

I haven't found a way currently to achieve this short of making the container privileged. I was hoping there'd be something settable in the securityContext, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the devices to the container is not currently supported in Kubernetes.  This issue is tracked in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5607